# ng2-charts does not work When data is between 2 and 5

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

ng2-charts does not work When data is between 2 and 5.

when data between 2 and 5 the chart does not work correct.
when data grater than 5 chart works.

[image]

[image]

```
public barChartOptions: any = {
        scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
              }
            }]
          },        
    };





 public barChartLabels: string[] = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 
  'June', 'July', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    public barChartType: string = 'bar';
    public barChartLegend: boolean = true;



 public barChartData: any[] =
    [
        { data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0, 0, 6, 0, 0], label: 'Transaction' },
        { data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], label: 'Ticket ' },
        { data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], label: 'Visit ' }
    ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set **`stepSize: 1`** for y-axis ticks :

```
...
public barChartOptions: any = {
   scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
   responsive: true,
   scales: {
      yAxes: [{
         ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
            stepSize: 1 //<- set this
         }
      }]
   },
};
...
```

Answer (score 0):

it does not have good view for large data amount.